# Datepicker set default date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set default date for Jquery datepicker on init. Here is my html:

```
var content = "";
            content = "<table class=\"filter-table\">";
            content += "<tr><td><label for='startDate'>From </label></td><td><input name='startDate' id='startDate' class='date-picker' /></td></tr>";
            content += "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";  
            content += "<tr><td><label for='endDate'>To </label></td><td><input name='endDate' id='endDate' class='date-picker'  /></td></tr>";
```

And my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showdatepicker() {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeDay: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var day = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-day :selected").val();
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $('#startDate').datepicker({defaultDate: -30});
                $('#endDate').datepicker({defaultDate: new Date()});
            }
        });
    }       
    </script>
```

What I am trying to do is set the date and show in the textbox when on load the page. The endDate should be current date whilst start date should be one month before. However, by using these codes, it does not display the date in textbox when first load.

I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, like you, could not use a method on the datepicker to populate a default date in the input.

So instead, I made code using vanilla JS to calculate the default dates and format them to display in the textboxes.

Here is the JS I added:

```
function showdatepicker() {
    // same as yours
}

function populateDefaultValues() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth() - 1,
        year = today.getFullYear();
    if (month < 0) {
        month = 11;
        year -= 1;
    }
    var oneMonthAgo = new Date(year, month, today.getDate());

    $('#startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', today));
    $('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', oneMonthAgo));
}

$(function() {
    populateDefaultValues();
    showdatepicker();
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/W4jGJ/)

Comment: It works, thanks. So basically I have to make two different functions for two different purpose?

Comment: Well, you could refactor it to keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). And you may find it useful to include a better library for managing dates like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com), which make it easier to construct a dates, taking everything into consideration like leap years, days in a month, etc. My method didn't quite do that, I realise now.

Comment: If you're just running that code once on page load, put it inside the `$(function(){` block instead.

Comment: @Wireblue Good point, that would prevent polluting the global namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: @GregL Thanks for mentioning MomentJS. Looks super handy!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `defaultDate` option. It provides exactly the features you need.

Because the default date options will vary for each datepicker you will need to initialise them separately (basically copy-paste, and tweak to suit).

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: But I thought this one was meant for setting the date at calendar but not the textbox itself?

Comment: Sorry, that's correct. @GregL's answer is the best one in this instance.